# Visual Studio 2010 visual basic page redirect not working

Tags: visual-studio-2010, response.redirect

On a second page in the system, I check for an user ID. If it hasn't been entered on the first page (they may jump directly to the second page), I'll redirect them to an error page.

The problem is everything hangs at that point.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If (Session("userName") Is Nothing Or
        Session("userName") = "") Then
        Response.Redirect("Error.aspx")
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/540y83hx%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Try:

```
Server.Transfer("Error.aspx", True)
```

p.s. don't get values from session like that. Use:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03sekbw5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

```
Dim username as String = CType(Session.Item("userName"), String)
```

and now check username 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx

```
Dim username as String = CType(Session.Item("userName"), String)
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(username) Then 
        Response.Redirect("Error.aspx")
```

Or

```
Dim username as String = CType(Session.Item("userName"), String)
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(username) Then 
         Server.Transfer("Error.aspx", True)
```